# Contradicting calculus proofs?

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

I'm in a Foundation of Mathematics course and one of the major topics on the syllabus is proofs. In class, we went over the multiple types of proofs and how to form them and from there I formed a question in my head. How could I relate this to calculus? So I ask if it's possible to contradict this calculus proof?

If $nx^{n-1}$ is the derivative of $x^n,$ then $2x$ is a derivative of $x^2.$

Comment: What's to contradict? That's the way it is, just like that.

Comment: Are you trying to ask for a proof by contradiction of the fact that $\frac{d}{dx} x^2 = 2x$?

Comment: @AndrewP. That is correct

Comment: Well, that is hardly a proof. You could be clearer what you mean by “$nx^{n-1}$ is the derivative of $x^n.$” You should say for what values of $n$ this is true. Obviously, if true for $n=2,$ then you are done. You might also be clearer that you mean the derivative with respect to $x,$ not $n,$ but usually we’d assume the derivative with expect to $x.$

Comment: Any provable statement can be proved by contradiction, but sometimes that's nothing but a pointless extra step.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I will be more clear next time!

Comment: “Contradict this calculus proof” in English means, “find what is wrong with it.” If that is not what you mean, but, as noted in your comment, that you are seeking a proof by contradiction, you should edit your question to make that clear. Although any proof by contradiction is likely to be artificial - ultimately this is a theorem with a direct proof, and any proof by contradiction will likely just be hiding the direct proof.

Comment: What you are trying to do is in broad terms very reasonable: given some proof techniques you learned about, you are trying to applying them to mathematical propositions that you are already familiar with. It's just that the example that you chose is way too simple (it consists of a single step: take $n := 2$) to have an interesting proof by contradiction. Of course, you could say "if it weren't the case that (x^2)' = 2x, then it wouldn't be the case that (x^n)' = nx^{n-1} for all $n$, but this contradicts the assumption that $(x^{n})' = nx^{n-1}$ for all $n$", but this is just wordplay.

Comment: From reading the comments, I concluded that the above proof can be contradicted but should have been a bit more clear when asking the question and forming the proof. I should've asked if it can be solved by "Proof of Contradiction"

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the English lessons that have been given in the comments above: The proof cannot be "contradicted", because saying this in English means that the "proof", and the statement proved, have been shown to be false. But your proof is not false. What you mean - and what you *need* to start saying when speaking English - that the theorem "can be proved *by contradiction*". This means that there is a proof that starts off by assuming the theorem is *false*, and then shows that the assumption of falsehood results in a contradiction.